# PHP: How to use switch statement to retrieve radio button values

Tags: php, switch-statement, radio-button

I'm working on a homework assignment while learning PHP for the first time. Everything is working, except for my switch statement. My professor is asking-

"Modify index.php

1. Get the selected value from the "calculate" radio button you created
2. Add a switch statement to set values for:

   1. only the average calculation if the user selected the "average" radio button
   2. only the total calculation if the user selected the "total" radio button
   3. both the average and total if the user selected the "both" button."

I'd like to provide my entire index.php file in case it's important to see everything-

```
<?php

//set default values to be used when page first loads
$scores = array();
$scores[0] = 70;
$scores[1] = 80;
$scores[2] = 90;

$scores_string = '';
$score_total = 0;
$score_average = 0;
$max_rolls = 0;
$average_rolls = 0;

$score_total_f = '';
$score_average_f = '';

//take action based on variable in POST array
$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
switch ($action) {
case 'process_scores':
$scores = $_POST['scores'];

// validate the scores
$is_valid = true;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($scores); $i++) {
    if (empty($scores[$i]) || !is_numeric($scores[$i])) {
        $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
        $is_valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$is_valid) {
    break;
}

// process the scores
$score_total = 0;
foreach ($scores as $s) {
    $scores_string .= $s . '|';
    $score_total += $s;
}
$scores_string = substr($scores_string, 0, strlen($scores_string)-1);

// calculate the average
$score_average = $score_total / count($scores);

// format the total and average
$score_total_f = number_format($score_total, 2);
$score_average_f = number_format($score_average, 2);


$calculate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'calculate');
switch($calculate) {
    case "average":
    $message_average = $score_average_f;
    break;
    case "total":
    $message_total = $score_total_f;
    break;
    case "both":
    $message_average = $score_average_f;
    $message_total = $score_total_f;
    break;
    default: die("Invalid type");
}

break;

case 'process_rolls':
    $number_to_roll = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number_to_roll', 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    $total = 0;       
    $max_rolls = -INF;

    for ($count = 0; $count < 10000; $count++) {
        $rolls = 1;
        while (mt_rand(1, 6) != $number_to_roll) {
            $rolls++;
        }
        $total += $rolls;            
        $max_rolls = max($rolls, $max_rolls);
    }
    $average_rolls = $total / $count;

    break;
}
include 'loop_tester.php';
?>
```

Also, here is part of the other file where I had to create radio buttons-

```
<h3>What do you want to do?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="calculate" value="average" checked> Average<br>
<input type="radio" name="calculate" value="total"> Total<br>
<input type="radio" name="calculate" value="both"> Both<br>

<label>Scores:</label>
    <span><?php echo htmlspecialchars($scores_string); ?></span><br>

    <label>Score Total:</label>
    <span><?php echo $message_total; ?></span><br>

    <label>Average Score:</label>
    <span><?php echo $message_average; ?></span><br>
</form>
```

Thank you!

Again, everything is working fine when I test in XAMPP, just not the switch statement. I get no output of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Disregard my original answer, I tested out your original syntax and it seems to work fine. Sorry, that was a mistake on my part, though I'd still say the new code is more elegant.

There seems to be an issue with a misplaced `break;` - Here is a full working code for to 'process_scores' case:

```
case 'process_scores':
    $scores = $_POST['scores'];

    // validate the scores
    $is_valid = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($scores); $i++) {
        if (empty($scores[$i]) || !is_numeric($scores[$i])) {
            $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
            $is_valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$is_valid) {
        break;
    }

    // process the scores
    $score_total = 0;
    foreach ($scores as $s) {
        $scores_string .= $s . '|';
        $score_total += $s;
    }
    $scores_string = substr($scores_string, 0, strlen($scores_string)-1);

    // calculate the average
    $score_average = $score_total / count($scores);

    // format the total and average
    $score_total_f = number_format($score_total, 2);
    $score_average_f = number_format($score_average, 2);


    $calculate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'calculate');
    $score_average_f = number_format($score_average, 2);
    $score_total_f = number_format($score_total, 2);
    switch($calculate) {
        case "average":
        echo "Average: " . $score_average_f;
        break;
        case "total":
        echo "Total: " . $score_total_f;
        break;
        case "both":
        echo "Average: " . $score_average_f . "<br />";
        echo "Total: " . $score_total_f;
        break;
        default: die("Invalid type");
    }

    break;
```

I'm not sure about other the other part of your code, but I tested this and got the intended results. If you still see nothing, check what's in your $_POST variables. Also as a general advice for debugging: in a situation like this, just go through your code and echo stuff out inside and outside of every loop or function you believe your code should reach, to see where it gets derailed. It may not sound too professional, but it sure gets the job done.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I edited this post for all to see your suggestion. Still no echo is displayed. Please double-check.

Comment: Hi, i took a look at it, and this is just a guess, but you seem to have a misplaced "break;" - before this line: "$calculate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'calculate');"  -> Since the rest of the logic is floating in a switch statement, it will never actually run. I can try your code locally soon to see if there are any other issues, I'll check back with you (unless you solve it until then).

Comment: Much appreciated! Let me know if you need my other file (all code).

Comment: Instead of using echo statements, can you help me fix the file so ONLY what ever radio button is checked, it is displayed on the web page. Right now I press the submit button, everything is being calculated along with the echo statements.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "everything is being calculated". If you mean you only want to see the end result after pressing submit, make the form's "action" attribute a separate php file with your logic. Otherwise please clarify, or update your question with your form, and what your expected result is, and what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for helping again. I posted above my final code. Everything is working like it should. When I test with XAMPP, it says "Notice: Undefined variable: message_total in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\ex_starts\ch08_ex2\loop_tester.php on line 40" and  "Notice: Undefined variable: message_average in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\ex_starts\ch08_ex2\loop_tester.php on line 43".

Comment: It appears I have variables not defined, but I don't understand where.

Comment: It says the line number in the error :) Sorry, I can't test this out until much later, but I ASSUME your problem is that you try to echo the message when you first load the page, even though it's not set yet, so the variable is undefined. You should only do display that whole part if the user has submitted the form. Encapsule that whole segment within something like this: <?php if(isset($_POST)) { ?>     ...   <?php } ?>

Comment: I figured it out. Wanted to let you know before you waste any time. Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same exercise. You need to define your variables before all the code runs.

```
$scores_string = '';
$score_total = 0;
$score_average = 0;
$max_rolls = 0;
$average_rolls = 0;
$message_average = 0;
$message_total = 0;
```

After I defined variables, `$message_average` and `$message_total`, everything worked fine.

Comment: Hi David! Yes, I finally figured this out. I was setting variables inside the switch statement.